# How to add dynamic fields using a counter to limit the number of fields in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the fiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/gKJEs/80/

I need a counter to stop the number of rows being added. lets say till 5.

HTML :

```
<table id="table"></table>
<button id="addRowBtn">Add Row</button>
```

Script:

```
$(function () {    
    var tbl = $("#table");    
    $("#addRowBtn").click(function () {    
        $("<tr class='tre'><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td><button class='delRowBtn'>Delete</button></td></tr>").appendTo(tbl);      
    });

    $('#sd').click(function () {
        $('.tre').hide();
    });

    $(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function () {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey see if it works for you, I've added a counter for checking the rows with same class.

```
   var numItems = jQuery('.tre').length
   if(numItems <5){  
     //add row
   }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gKJEs/84/

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a counter variable and check like this:-

```
if(counter>5){
        alert("Only 5 fields allow");
        return false;
}
```

[Here is reference link](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/how-to-add-remove-textbox-dynamically-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it and updted fiddle kindly see http://jsfiddle.net/gKJEs/85/

```
enter code here$(function(){

var tbl = $("#table");
var numRows = 0;
$("#addRowBtn").click(function(){
    if(numRows<5){
    $("<tr class='tre'><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td>Lorem Ipsum</td><td><button class='delRowBtn'>Delete</button></td></tr>").appendTo(tbl);  
numRows++;
   }        
});
   $('#sd').click(function(){
       $('.tre').hide();
   });

$(document.body).delegate(".delRowBtn", "click", function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").remove();
numRows--;        
}); 

});
```